# Activity and Fragment Lifecycle, does the onResume fire one after the other?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, activity-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

I am wondering what the proper order goes when a user returns to an `Activity` from the `Home Screen`.

Will the `Activity's onResume()` execute first, and then the `Fragment's onResume()` execute after? Does it do it in order, or will it do it concurrently?

I put some code in my Fragment's onResume() but it doesn't seem to be firing after the Activity's onResume().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am wondering what the proper order goes when a user returns to an
>   Activity from the Home Screen.

Activity's onResume() execute and the Fragment's onResume() execute after. Here is my screen shot of the log:

[image]

> Will the Activity's onResume() execute first, and then the Fragment's
>   onResume() execute after? Does it do it in order, or will it do it
>   concurrently?

Yes, the two onResume() method execute in order, because they are all executed on the main thread(also called ui thread, it's a single thread), so there is no concurrent problem.

> I put some code in my Fragment's onResume() but it doesn't seem to be
>   firing after the Activity's onResume().

I think there is something wrong with your code, you can check it again or post it here, so someone may point your mistake.

Answer (score 3):

The fragments `onResume()` or `onPause()` will be called only after the Activities `onResume()` or `onPause()` is called. They are tightly coupled to the `Activity`.

[Read the Fragment Lifecycle section of this article.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle)